# xmlViewResolver not allow to start StandardContext (Error listenerStart)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

`org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xmlViewResolver` generates an error when JBOSS tries to start `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`.

I added this line in my *mvc-config.xml* file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/views.xml" />
    <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I have the file *views.xml* that I reference from *mvc-config.xml*, but when I try to start jboss, the following error appears:

```
10:15:57,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activando WebServices Extension
10:15:58,309 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010408: Iniciando JCA sub-sistema (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.11.Final-redhat-1)
10:15:58,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Versión PicketBox actual=4.0.9.Final-redhat-1
10:15:59,651 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Iniciando el servicio de nombrado
10:15:59,744 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015400: Sesión de correo enlazada [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:16:00,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Implementación del controlador que cumple con los requerimientos de JDBC class org.h2.Driver (versión 1.3)
10:16:02,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Implementación del controlador que cumple con los requerimientos de JDBC class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (versión 11.2)
10:16:04,355 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.4.GA-redhat-1
10:16:06,248 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:jboss/innova_filia]
10:16:06,289 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:jboss/innova_inte]
10:16:06,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:/jdbc/entitlement]
10:16:06,318 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:16:06,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:jboss/innova_local]
10:16:06,293 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Fuente de datos enlazados [java:jboss/innova]
10:16:07,023 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-7) Arrancando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-/127.0.0.1:8084
10:16:08,158 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Inició FileSystemDeploymentService para el directorio C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\deployments
10:16:08,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Iniciando la implementación de "ROOT.war"
10:16:08,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Escuchando en 127.0.0.1:10003
10:16:08,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Escuchando en 127.0.0.1:4451
10:16:24,141 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry com.ibm.mq.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mq-5.300-j530-L021008.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,145 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry com.ibm.mq.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.mqbind-5.300-j530-L021008.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,153 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,157 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,160 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,165 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,178 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,185 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-beanutils.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,192 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-digester.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,197 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-fileupload.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,208 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-logging.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,213 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-validator.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:24,225 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jakarta-oro.jar in /C:/Program Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:16:25,549 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018567: La implementación "deployment.ROOT.war" está utilizando un módulo privado ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters:main"), el cual se puede cambiar o borrar en versiones futuras sin previo aviso.
10:16:25,553 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018567: La implementación "deployment.ROOT.war" está utilizando un módulo privado ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters:main"), el cual se puede cambiar o borrar en versiones futuras sin previo aviso.
10:16:26,834 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

10:16:26,838 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

10:16:26,840 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @51c888d9 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\modules)] whereas object of type 

10:16:26,843 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

10:16:26,847 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LIB".

10:16:26,850 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR A "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

10:16:26,854 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

10:16:26,856 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @51c888d9 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\modules)] whereas object of type 

10:16:26,859 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

10:16:26,862 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "GLTCEmergency".

10:16:26,870 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR A "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

10:16:26,873 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

10:16:26,878 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @51c888d9 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\modules)] whereas object of type 

10:16:26,884 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

10:16:26,891 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "GLL".

10:16:26,893 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR A "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

10:16:26,899 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

10:16:26,902 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @51c888d9 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\modules)] whereas object of type 

10:16:26,923 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR "com.todo1.lg.GLLAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

10:16:26,925 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "Recovery".

10:16:26,927 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

10:16:26,933 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

10:16:26,934 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @51c888d9 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\modules)] whereas object of type 

10:16:26,939 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader].

10:16:26,951 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RecoveryData".

10:16:27,010 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: No se está instalando el componente opcional org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest debido a una excepción: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: No pudo encontrar el constructor predeterminadp para class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:83) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

10:16:27,048 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011006: No se está instalando el componente opcional org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl debido a una excepción: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: No pudo encontrar el constructor predeterminadp para class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:83) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

10:16:27,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.ROOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
10:16:28,453 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:27,735 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]

10:16:28,454 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:27,737 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]

10:16:28,455 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:27,739 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [vfs:/C:/Program%20Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]

10:16:28,461 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:27,757 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@89990ff - URL [vfs:/C:/Program%20Files/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] is not of type file

10:16:28,468 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set

10:16:28,471 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,009 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds

10:16:28,474 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,009 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[]] every 30 seconds. 

10:16:28,477 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,009 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter

10:16:28,480 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,011 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]

10:16:28,482 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]

10:16:28,483 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,084 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used

10:16:28,484 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,085 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern C:/todo1/Banistmo/logs/psflogs/svpBanistmoTX.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i for the active file

10:16:28,485 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,090 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@19fe59c2 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'C:/todo1/Banistmo/logs/psflogs/svpBanistmoTX.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i'.

10:16:28,486 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,090 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@19fe59c2 - Roll-over at midnight.

10:16:28,487 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,122 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@19fe59c2 - Setting initial period to Tue Jun 10 16:07:34 ART 2014

10:16:28,488 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,309 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property

10:16:28,488 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,352 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.

10:16:28,489 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,352 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.

10:16:28,504 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,352 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details

10:16:28,505 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,354 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: C:\todo1\Banistmo\logs\psflogs/svpBanistmoTX.log

10:16:28,506 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,354 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [C:\todo1\Banistmo\logs\psflogs/svpBanistmoTX.log]

10:16:28,507 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,357 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR

10:16:28,508 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,358 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]

10:16:28,508 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.

10:16:28,509 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 10:16:28,450 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@9b6dce3 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

10:16:28,510 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) 

10:16:52,801 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Error listenerStart
10:16:52,803 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Falló en arranque del Contexto [] debido a errores previos
10:16:52,909 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Falló iniciar contexto
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

10:16:53,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Implementado "ROOT.war"
10:16:53,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Reporte del estatus del servicio
JBAS014777: Servicios que no lograron iniciar:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ROOT: JBAS018040: Falló iniciar contexto

10:16:53,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Consola de administración escuchando en http://127.0.0.1:9994
10:16:53,562 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1)  inició (con errores) en 69947ms - Inició 477 de 566 servicios (2 servicios fallaron o faltan dependencias, 81 servicios son pasivos o por demanda)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: There must be more to the logs than this. Enable Spring's logging as well so we can see what it has to say.

Comment: I added the complete log. Thanks again